# Problems with tornado coroutine. Doesn't run asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, yield, coroutine

After some painful attempts I wrote something like this:

```
urls=[
            'http://localhost',
            'http://www.baidu.com',
            'http://www.taobao.com',
            'http://www.163.com',
            'http://www.sina.com',
            'http://www.qq.com',
            'http://www.jd.com',
            'http://www.amazon.cn',
        ]


@tornado.gen.coroutine
def fetch_with_coroutine(url):

    response=yield tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(url)
    print url,len(response.body)
    raise tornado.gen.Return(response.body)


@tornado.gen.coroutine
def main():
    for url in urls:
        yield fetch_with_coroutine(url)


timestart=time.time()
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(main)
print 'async:',time.time()-timestart
```

but it's even a little slower than the synchronous code. In addition the order of output is always the same so I think it doesn't run asynchronously.
What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

In `main()`, you're calling `fetch_with_coroutine` one at a time; the way you're using `yield` means that the second fetch can't start until the first is finished. Instead, you need to start them all first and wait for them with a single yield:

```
@gen.coroutine
def main():
    # 'fetches' is a list of Future objects.
    fetches = [fetch_with_coroutine(url) for url in urls]
    # 'responses' is a list of those Futures' results
    # (i.e. HTTPResponse objects).
    responses = yield fetches
```